# Stackable trait/decorator and abstract class

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have an abstract class (Java library) that takes constructor arguments and has a method called `execute` that I want to decorate:

```
public abstract class Task {
    private final String name;

    protected Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public abstract void execute(String str) throws Exception
}
```

And I have Scala classes that currently inherit the previous one:

```
class FooTask extends Task("fooTask") {
  override def execute(str: String): Unit = println(str + "foo")
}

class BarTask extends Task("barTask") {
  override def execute(str: Strin): Unit = println(str + "bar")
}
```

Is it possible to write a decorator for a Task class like this:

```
trait TaskWithErrorLogging { self: Task =>

  override def execute(str: String): Unit =
    Try(self.execute(str)) match {
      case Failure(exception) =>
        println("LOGGED " + exception)
        throw exception;
      case _ =>
    }

}
```

And then use it in order to log errors?

```
class BarTask extends Task("barTask") with TaskWithErrorLogging {
  override def execute(str: String): Unit = println(str + "bar") // Error should be logged
}
```

These tasks are being instantiated automatically by framework's injector, so there is no way to write `new FooTask with TaskWithErrorLogging`

Currently, decorator's overridden method is being ignored (it compiles, but does not execute). Adding `abstract` modifier to the method in decorator does not compile. What is the right way to implement this logging solution? Maybe there is another option except for a stackable trait?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but if `tasks are being instantiated automatically by framework` then you just can't use stackable trait decorator approach because it's compile-time feature. Creating `stack` by using `with` is  the same as if you declare new class. You can't declare class based on already created object.

Comment: I mean that I can not declare that `class BarTask extends Task("barTask")` and then write `new BarTask with TaskWithErrorLogging`, I can only write `class BarTask extends Task("barTask")  with TaskWithErrorLogging`

Comment: As I wrote, this aproach does not work or doe not compile (depends on whether you add an `abstract` modifier to the trait)

Comment: btw your trait `TaskWithErrorLogging` can't be compiled in scala because it has java-specific parameter declaration.

Comment: I fixed code description, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently, decorator's overridden method is being ignored (it compiles, but does not execute)

It doesn't execute because it's overridden in `BarTask`. And if it did execute, it has infinite recursion: `self.execute(str)` will call the same method.

The simplest way is

```
trait TaskWithErrorLogging extends Task {
  override def execute(str: String): Unit =
    Try(doExecute(str)) match {
      case Failure(exception) =>
        println("LOGGED " + exception)
        throw exception;
      case _ =>
    }

  def doExecute(str: String): Unit
}

class BarTask extends Task("barTask") with TaskWithErrorLogging {
  override def doExecute(str: String): Unit = println(str + "bar")
}
```

Or if you really want to go with stackable decorators, then `TaskWithErrorLogging` still needs to be mixed in *after* the method it decorates, e.g.

```
trait TaskWithErrorLogging extends Task { 
  abstract override def execute(str: String): Unit =
    Try(super.execute(str)) match { // note super, not self!
      case Failure(exception) =>
        println("LOGGED " + exception)
        throw exception;
      case _ =>
    }
}

class BarTask0 extends Task("barTask") {
  override def execute(str: String): Unit = println(str + "bar")
}

class BarTask extends BarTask0 with TaskWithErrorLogging
```

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way except of adding another method with a different name instead of calling `execute` directly?